# Telerik kendo ui Asp.Net MVC Pivotgrid Custom Column Header Text

Tags: asp.net, kendo-ui, asp.net-mvc-5, telerik

I want to change pivotgrid column Caption text.

When columns.Add ("BranchType") is changed as a custom text columns.Add ("Ünvan") it shows text "ünvan&undefined". BranchType comes from model.

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks.